# Rendering is not done on android studio

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I just started learning Android app development and encountered an issue of rendering problem

The exact words are

> Exception raised during rendering: You must specify a valid layout reference. The layout ID sdv is not valid.
>    After clicking on details I got
>   android.view.InflateException: You must specify a valid layout reference. The layout ID sdv is not valid.

My activity_main.xml code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.ayush.myfirstapp.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="sdv"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: post your code please

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `<include layout="@layout/sdv" />`. You forgot the `@layout`.

The line is located in the marked section:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.ayush.myfirstapp.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- This line is wrong -->
    <include layout="sdv"/>
    <!-- end of wrong part -->

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific where to add the above line you commented. I am new to such enviroment.

Comment: I indicated the mistake, you still need to replace the line with `<include layout="@layout/sdv" />`

Comment: Exception raised during rendering: You must specify a layout in the include tag: <include layout="@layout/layoutID" />
Still this line is coming

Answer (score 0):

**Wrong:**

```
<include layout="sdv"/>
```

**Good:**

```
 <include layout="@layout/sdv"/>
```

Comment: Exception raised during rendering: You must specify a layout in the include tag: <include layout="@layout/layoutID" /> After that this error is coming